# My uninstall module tab is almost empty

Tags: installation

hello to the drupal pro,

I have over **50 disable modules listed** on my module list page but **only one** appear under the **uninstall tab**. (Toolbar module)

I discovered that when i wanted to uninstall a module for the first time

**Any idea** why?

PS: i'm running my drupal site on the localhost using WAMP server

Answer (score 3):

Modules only appear listed on the uninstall tab if they have been enabled and then disabled at some point in the past, AND if they actually installed something in the database that can be uninstalled (i.e. custom tables, variables, etc.) OR they implement hook_uninstall, even if they don't install anything in the database.

Comment: OR if they implement [`hook_uninstall`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7) even if they haven't installed anything in the DB. +1 for now, but please add this.

Comment: Yes, good point. Fixed now.

Comment: So to uninstall a module that didn't modify the db i just delete manually the associated folder on my ftp server?

Comment: Right, if you don't want a module to appear in your module list, and it's not installed, and the module didn't modify the database (if it ever was enabled), you can just remove the module directory. But this really only makes sense for contributed modules that you've downloaded yourself, and decided not to use.

Comment: yeah sure. Thanks dave for taking time to help newbies :)

Comment: No worries. Drupal is big and intimidating :)